# How to disable Yoast SEO adding article:author meta tags to pages

Tags: wordpress

The excellent Yoast SEO plugin is adding some unwanted meta tags.

For example, I would like `article:author` to appear on posts, but not on pages or other content types.

Is there a way to adjust this globally?

I'm happy to edit `functions.php`, but I'm just unsure what I should be hooking in to.

I would be grateful for any pointers from those more familiar with the plugin.

I tried this:

```
function wpseo_show_article_author_only_on_posts() {
  if ( !is_single() ) {
    return false;
  }
}
add_filter( 'xxxxxx', 'wpseo_show_article_author_only_on_posts' );
```

I need to know what hook should replace `xxxxxx`.

Comment: Nothing on the "page edition" page ? Since this is more a settings question than a coding one, you should ask this on Yoast SEO support forum, or Wordpress.com /.org, or in http://wordpress.stackexchange.com, which may be more relevent...

Comment: Where is the 'page edition' page? There doesn't appear to be a setting for this, so had thought I would need to code something. Anyway, I will relocate to the tumble weeds of wordpress.stackexchange.com. Thanks!

Comment: "page edition" page is the page where you write a new pages in wordpress, and where you see every existant pages... the common one you know :)

Comment: oh yes, sorry. there are options to edit per-page meta-title, -description and -image, but not enable/disable author tags. And irrespective, this site has 80+ pages so I'm really looking for a global fix. I expect there is a filter that I could hook into in functions.php, I just don't know what it is and have not been able to track down any docs. Thanks for the pointers to other sites

Comment: funny! wordpress.stackexchange has just flagged this Q as off topic and more appropriate for SO!!!

Comment: yeah, because you should ask  Yoast SEO plugin support forum for this kind of question, your question is too specific to be answered here. You must have a guideline before comming on SE/SO. This forum is more a "I tried this, this, and this, but doesn't work, how can I do". Here, you only have the "how can I do ?" part... :)

Comment: added 'i tried this' to the q, but appreciate your point this is plugin specific

Comment: So adding this part, you see this is specific to the plugin. You did the PHP/Wordpress part (the only part we may help you with). What is missing is the plugin part (where we can't do anything for you).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the `wpseo_opengraph_author_facebook` filter, which ties into the `article_author_facebook()` method in `frontend/class-opengraph.php` of the plugin.

```
function wpseo_show_article_author_only_on_posts( $facebook ) {
    if ( ! is_single() ) {
        return false;
    }
    return $facebook;
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_opengraph_author_facebook', 'wpseo_show_article_author_only_on_posts', 10, 1 );
```

---

The `article_author_facebook()` method does a check for [`is_singular()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular), which checks that we're viewing single page, post or attachment:

> This conditional tag checks if a singular post is being displayed, which is the case when one of the following returns true: `is_single()`, `is_page()` or `is_attachment()`. If the `$post_types` parameter is specified, the function will additionally check if the query is for one of the post types specified.

The additional filter for `( ! is_single() )` ensures that `article:author` is only added to posts.

Comment: you sir are the man. thank you kindly! And +1 for a great answer

Comment: I have tried but not working. i have to remove meta tags <meta name="author" content="abc@gmail.com" class="yoast-seo-meta-tag" />.. when i am sharing the post then i am getting Written By so i have to remove it

Answer (score 1):

If people are looking for a way to remove more yoast SEO tags, just lookup the file wordpress-seo/frontend/class-opengraph.php, and you can see which filters you can hook into to remove certain tags.

This is the code I use to remove these tags from pages: url, image, title, description and type:

```
function remove_yoast_og_tags( $ogTag ){
    // Do a check of which type of post you want to remove the tags from
    if ( is_page() ) {
        return false;
    }
    return $ogTag;
}


$yoastTags = array(
    "url",
    "image",
    "title",
    "desc",
    "type"
);
foreach ($yoastTags as $tag) {
    add_filter( 'wpseo_opengraph_'.$tag, 'remove_yoast_og_tags');
}
```